# Avoid override ENTRYPOINT base docker image

Tags: docker

I have a base docker image pointing to `daggerok/jboss-eap-7.1:7.1.0-alpine` and it execute a `ENTRYPOINT` that i don't want to override. But i also need execute another command after base image execute theirs, so my Dockerfile looks like it:

```
FROM daggerok/jboss-eap-7.1:7.1.0-alpine

#SOME CODE HERE

ENTRYPOINT ["mybash.sh"]
```

I think this code override ENTRYPOINT in base image, and i need avoid it. My script need to be executed after all commands in base image.

Any tips to solve it ?

Comment: You can try to wait in `mybash.sh` with `sleep` to see if it really override the command

Comment: do you think mybash.sh is executing before the ENTRYPOINT in base image?

Comment: Why not using CMD?

Comment: because with CMD user that use "docker run" can override command

Comment: Call the original entry point from your `mybash.sh` script as the first action.

Comment: @RonaldoLanhellas I would create a new image from your base image, add as main content your current base image entrypoint which you don't want to override and as entrypoint `mybash.sh`.

Comment: @RonaldoLanhellas: Be aware that users can also override the entrypoint. They can do `docker run --entrypoint /bin/bash` for example.

Comment: yeah, i know that but with entrypoint is more difficult to override a default command than CMD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems to achieve what you want:

- You cannot find out the `ENTRYPOINT` of the base image at runtime within a .sh-script, so you cannot execute it, without copying it explicitly into your `mybash.sh`
- The `ENTRYPOINT` of the base image you mention is `/bin/bash ${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/standalone.sh` which launches the main process with id 1 of your docker container. You should not alter that and start this in background for example. Read further [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/).

I would advise to rewrite mybash.sh:
First execute whatever you would like before starting jboss. Then, finish your script with a last line starting jboss:
`exec "/bin/bash ${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/standalone.sh"` (adapted from [here](https://success.docker.com/article/use-a-script-to-initialize-stateful-container-data))

Comment: so, you suggest that i should override ENTRYPOINT from base image ? If yes, just adding ENTRYPOINT to last line of my dockerfile will override it ?

Comment: Thanks @fab. You answer was very useful